# Batch - How to rename and move file, if file already exists

Tags: batch-file

### Good day!

So, my problem is, I am making script, that will move Archives from one folder to another. Problem is, IF archive already exists, then Archive from second folder will be replaced.

These ar Backup Archives, and I want to create backups on any given date.

Here is what I have so far:

```
set year=%DATE:~6,4%

if not exist "V:\01_%YEAR%" mkdir "V:\01_%YEAR%"  - Creates folder 01_2016
for /d %%X in (01_%YEAR%) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X\" - Archivates folder
MOVE "V:\01_%YEAR%.7z" "Z:\"  - moves Archive.
```

Now, idea is, that I write simple If exists code, that will rename Archive that I want to send, to something like this - 01_%YEAR%(1) and then send to folder.

Here is what I came up with:

```
if exist "Z:\01_%YEAR%.7z" (
ren V:\01_%YEAR%.7z 01_%YEAR%(1).7z
)
```

Ofcourse my idea is completely wrong, becouse next time I will run this script, archive will be replaced any way.

So, my question is, how can I improve my code?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help...

you need

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

replace

```
MOVE "V:\01_%YEAR%.7z" "Z:\"
```

by

```
set "last=0"
set "filename=Z:\01_%YEAR%.7z"

if exist "Z:\01_%YEAR%.7z" (
    for /R %%i in ("Z:\01_%YEAR%(*).7z") do (
       for /F "tokens=2 delims=(^)" %%a in ("%%i") do if %%a GTR !last! set "last=%%a"
    )
    set/a last+=1
    set "filename=Z:\01_%YEAR%(!last!).7z"    
)    

MOVE "V:\01_%YEAR%.7z" "%filename%"
```

> EDIT:  brief explanation

First, we set the desired destination filename **Z:\01_%YEAR%.7z**.

Then we check if file already exist. If it doesn't, we skip the block so **move** will use the content of filename, that is untouched **Z:\01_%YEAR%.7z**.

But if file exist, we enter the block.

The first **for** checks for all ocurrences of the pattern **Z:\01_%YEAR%(*).7z** where * may be anything.

Again, if there isn't any match, we jump to **set/a last+=1** (before last=0, now last=1), so filename now will be **Z:\01_%YEAR%(1).7z**

If there is any match, the second **for** will be executed. Here the result of the first block is scanned, and the part between parentheses extracted. So it may be 1,2,3,... from previous executions. Once, there aren't more matches we reach the **set/a last+=1** line, but now (i.e from previous) as **last=1**, after *set/a last+=1*, **last=2**, so filename now will be **Z:\01_%YEAR%(2).7z**

So each time the (*) part in incremented by one.

Note: **this is not perfect code**, as the * in `for /R` may return strings, **but is a good starting point**.

Type **for /?** for more details

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey, wow, I am newbie in creating batch scripts, so I wanted to ask you, could you please explain, how this code works exactly? Or maybe MOVE "V:\01_%YEAR%.7z" "%filename%" in particular? Thank you very much. :)